# Applescript: Duplicate selection (folder) to desktop and moving the folder to a different location

Tags: variables, applescript, directory

First of, i'm an applescript noob;-)  What I'm asking for is simple but impossible for me to execute. See the script below.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    set the defaultPath to path to desktop folder as alias
    duplicate selection to defaultPath

    --I want to take take selection variable that is duplicated to the desktop and move that folder icon to the bottom of my screen.
    set desktop position of selection to {1400, 1200}
end tell

Here is the error I get ----> error "Finder got an error: Can’t set desktop position of selection to {1400, 1200}." number -10006 from desktop position of selection
```

In this example, I have 1 folder named "12345_SomeFile" as a selection. I'd love to be able to use the selection variable to do other things such as move, open and move window to a specific location. Hopefully this makes sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selection` returns a list of selected items so I assume you want to duplicate the first item of the selection.
I assume also that the setting `sorted by` of the desktop is set to none

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    if selected_items is not {} then
        set newItem to duplicate item 1 of selected_items to desktop
        set desktop position of newItem to {1400, 1200}
    end if
end tell
```